# NumPy log function throws attribute error for int

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, logistic-regression

I am trying to use a log loss function and keep getting the following error-

```
   AttributeError: log
```

the line of code that is throwing this error is -

```
ll = sum(act*sp.log(pred) + sp.subtract(1,act)*sp.log(sp.subtract(1,pred)))
```

where pred is-

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0......1]
```

and act is-

```
[[0     1]
 [1     1]
 [2     1]
 [3     1]
 [4     1]
 [5     1]
 [6     1]
 [7     1]
 [8     1]
 [9     1]
 .
 .
 .
 [n     1]]
```

Can someone help me with this? Completely driven up the wall.

Comment: I don't see `Y` or `T` in your equation

Comment: What are the dtypes of your arrays?  It is probably this bug: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1611

Comment: Continuing @BrenBarn's comment: What is `pred.dtype`?  I suspect `pred` is an object array (i.e. `pred.dtype` is `dtype('O')`).  If you print `pred`, you'll probably see something like `array([...numbers...], dtype=object)`.  As a work-around, replace `pred` with `pred.astype(int)` (or `pred.astype(float)` if the values are floating point) in your expression for `ll`.

Comment: @Cyber - just corrected my question

Comment: In my previous comment, when I said "If you print...", what I actually had in mind was the output shown in an interactive shell such as ipython if you simply entered `pred` by itself on an input line.  If you use the `print` statement, you'll need to use `print repr(pred)` to see what I expected you'll see.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - changing the type to float seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@WarrenWeckesser's answer helped me-

> "As a work-around, replace pred with pred.astype(int) (or pred.astype(float) if the values are floating point) in your expression for ll"